# How to add copy files to Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running a python script to manipulate pictures. When I run the test the system obviously does not find the images. I new to docker and don't really understand how to do that.

This is how the structure looks
[image]

And this is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install python3 -y
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip install pillow
RUN pip install wand
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends -y

WORKDIR /usr/app/src
COPY image_converter.py ./
COPY test_image_converter.py ./

RUN python3 -m unittest test_image_converter.py
```

Comment: With `COPY`, you should be able to do that. You may as well just copy the whole project directory with `COPY . .`.

Comment: either copy the image into the image, on build, or mount the image folder as volume when running the container. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY image_converter.py ./
COPY test_image_converter.py ./
```

here you've **COPIED** `****.py` file to `./`(== `WORKDIR`)

so, in the same way copy your image files to your `WORKDIR`

such as

```
COPY test_images ./
```

This should work

Comment: I tried that way, it still returns the same error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_images/solvee-logo-black-small.png'

Comment: @MikeHovhannisyan, its because the COPY instruction works differently from linux cp. In this case, it strips the parent folder. It should be `COPY test_images ./test_images`

Comment: although it returned this message set_mempolicy: Operation not permitted
all the tests passed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this will help, but try to look its content.

**https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copying-files-to-and-from-docker-containers/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the Fool gave the solution. I had to add this line
COPY test_images ./test_images

Answer (score 0):

- First, you didn't copy the image folder, should have these commands:

  WORKDIR /usr/app/src

  COPY test_images ./
- Second, you should combine same type of Docker commands (to reduce layers, hence reduce docker image's size)
  example : instead of saying

  COPY image_converter.py ./

  COPY test_image_converter.py ./

You can write

```
COPY *.py ./
```

Another example :

RUN apt update

RUN apt install python3 -y

You can write

> RUN apt update; apt install python3 -y